# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInitialNotification' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) in my react-native app currently testing on an Android device.
I have implemented the configure function inside `componentDidMount` as below

```
componentDidMount() {
    PushNotification.configure({
        onRegister: token => console.log('Token', token),
        onNotification: notification => console.log('NOTIFICATION', notification),
        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        },
        popInitialNotification: true,
        requestPermissions: true,
    });

PushNotification.localNotification(AppData.Notifications.localNotification);
}
```

When I reload the the app, I get error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInitialNotification' of undefined`

[image: Screenshot of error I am getting]

I am pretty new to react-native-push-notification and must be getting something small wrong

Comment: You many need to make that screenshot bigger. I don't think anyone can read it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve problem by editing `android/app/build.gradle` and adding the necessary dependencies as listed in the documentation. 
This had to be done even when `react-native link` is used. 
I cleaned, and rebuilt the project and the notification worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for push notification, its pretty much good, easy to implement and works smoothly.

https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm